# What does $\delta$ mean in calculus of variations

Tags: calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

For example in vector calculus we have a directional derivative $\nabla_vf(u)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(u+hv)-f(u)}{h}$ now what is the definition of $\delta$ in variational calculus? if it is the directional derivative in direction of some function then what is that function? Or is it like gradient a vector of derivatives for all possible functions?

Comment: Obviously this symbol is very common, but in the calculus of variations I remember it in the book Herman H. Goldstine - A History of the Calculus of Variations from the 17th through the 19th Century -Springer-Verlag, New York , 1980, page 275, as Kronecker delta.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_derivative